# Specify subframe for elements of id-value property map in a JSON-LD frame

Tags: rdf, json-ld, linked-data

I am trying to write a JSON-LD frame that serializes some RDF documents in a consistent way. Currently, the RDF is being parsed out from JSON-LD that is correctly structured and I would like the frame to return it in exactly the same way as it came from; later, I will have disparate sources of RDF documents and want them serialized like this too.

The whole example is [here](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-framed&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22steps%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22pwo%3AhasStep%22%2C%22%40container%22%3A%5B%22%40id%22%5D%7D%2C%22next-step%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22pwo%3AhasNextStep%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%2C%22first-step%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22pwo%3AhasFirstStep%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%7D%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22pwo%3AWorkflow%22%2C%22first-step%22%3A%22_%3Ab0%22%2C%22steps%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab0%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22zero%22%2C%22next-step%22%3A%22_%3Ab1%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab1%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22one%22%2C%22next-step%22%3A%22_%3Ab2%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Ab2%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22two%22%7D%5D%7D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22steps%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22pwo%3AhasStep%22%2C%22%40container%22%3A%5B%22%40id%22%5D%7D%2C%22next-step%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22pwo%3AhasNextStep%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%2C%22first-step%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22pwo%3AhasFirstStep%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%7D%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22pwo%3AWorkflow%22%7D). But I will explain my issue with abbreviations for some details, which can be found on the playground.

There is a Named Node of interest, and three Blank Nodes that are all of the same structure (each is a pwo:Step). Each blank node may point to the Next blank node; the Named node points to all three, as well as its First.

input-document.jsonld

```
{ "@context": { ... },
  "@type": "pwo:Workflow",
  "first-step": "_:b0",
  "steps": {
    "_:b0": { "next-step": "_:b1", ...values },
    "_:b1": { "next-step": "_:b2", ...values },
    "_:b2": { ...values },
  }
}
```

When I attempt to FRAME this document with the following frame:

```
{ "@context": { ... },
  "@type": "pwo:Workflow"
}
```

it gets denormalized so that the structure is more like this:

```
{ "@context": { ... },
  "@type": "pwo:Workflow",
  "first-step" {
    "@id": "_:b1",
    "next-step": {
      "@id": "_:b2",
      "next-step": { ...}
    }
  },
  "steps": {
    "_:b1": {},
    "_:b2": {},
    "_:b3": {}
  }
}
```

As you can see, the steps are each embedded in the `first-step` section instead of the `steps` section.

I was able to avoid this partially by changing the frame like so:

```
... 
  "@type":  "pwo:Workflow",
  "first-step": {
    "@embed": "@never"
  }
}
```

However, it still embeds each subsequent step under the `next-step` of the prior step.

How can I make my frame, which is referring at the top level to the `pwo:Workflow` object, also specify something like `@embed: @never` for the child object properties (next-step)? Mainly I have been unable to figure out the syntax for referring to those nested properties such as `next-step`. Things like this give opaque errors about failure to parse jsonld:

```
...
  "@type":  "pwo:Workflow",
  "first-step": {
    "@embed": "@never"
  },
  "steps": {
    "next-step": {
      "@embed": "@never"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found that the errors I got regarding failure to parse jsonld were corrected when I used the CURIE instead of the json-ld link when specifying the nested object`.

```
{
  ...
  "first-step": {"@embed": "@never"},
  "pwo:hasStep": {
    "@embed": "@always",
    "next-step": {"@embed": "@never"},
    "previous-step": {"@embed": "@never"}
  }
}
```